# MVC javascript redirect page not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, postback, http-redirect

In MVC, the default views for a controller allow one to reach the edit page via selecting an item in an index and using that id to reach the specific edit page.

In this MVC edit page, I have a javascript that reacts to a change in a dropdown.  The dropdown represents a subset of the potential id's available from the index page, and in general, someone will choose a different one than the currently displayed one.

The postback to the control works correctly in C#, and I can find the relevant model that goes with the id.  It all appears correct on the C# controller side.  However, when I try to get it to redirect back to the same edit page but with a different id (that from the dropdown), the page reverts back to the ajax call.

Is there anyway to "short-circuit" the ajax call so that it "knows" that it doesn't return but lets the C# redirect to the edit page (just like what happens when an element is chosen from the index page).

Thanks in advance,

Joseph Doggie

Comment: Can you post your code please? Both the controller and the client-side JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are making ajax requet, then you have to implement a way to redirect.
Depends on your ajax protocol... Are you returning json? html ...

If returning json, you could add a flag in your response telling wether this is a redirect answer and do redirect in js :

window.location = url

Answer (score 0):

OK, there is at least one way to do this.

Assume editing X with Controller named YController:

JavaScript:
var MyControllerUrlSettings = {
    MyControllerPrepareModifyXInfoUrl: '@Url.Action("PrepareModifyAssetInfo", "Y", new { x_txt = "**param**" })'
}

one then has a JavaScript to handle the dropdown change:

```
$('#ModelXList').change(function () {
        //// alert('Change detected');
        if ($("#ModelXList").val() != "") {
            //// alert('Reached here');
            var XNbrString = $("#ModelXList").val();
            var trimmedXNbrString = $.trim(XNbrString);
            //// debugger;
            if (trimmedXNbrString != "") {

                var url = MyControllerUrlSettings.MyControllerPrepareXInfoUrl;
                window.location.href = url.replace('__param__', trimmedXNbrString);
            }
        }
        else {
        }
    });
```

Finally, in the controller, there is a method:

```
public ActionResult PrepareModifyXInfo(string XNbr_txt)
        {
            // we cannot save anything here to cdll_cdcloanerlist;
            // static variables must be used instead.

            /// .... do what you have to do....

            return RedirectToAction("ModifyEdit", new { XNbr_txt = XNbr_txt });
        }
```

Note:  For proprietary reasons, I changed some of the syntax so that everything would be general, therefore, you may have to work with the above code a little, but it works

Alternate answers are really welcome, also!